# What is the average size ratio between a data file and ETS table?

Tags: erlang, ets

I am evaluating the use of Erlang ETS to store a large in-memory data set that. My test data source is a CSV file that consumes only 350 MBytes of disk.

My parser reads row by row and splices it into a list, then create a **tuple** and stores it in **ETS**, using a "bag" configuration.

After loading all the data in ETS I noticed that my computer's 8GB of RAM was all gone, and the OS had created virtual memory, occupying somewhere near 16GB or RAM. The erlang's Beam process seems to take a consume about **10 times** fold more memory than the size of disk data.

Here is the **test code**:

```
-module(load_test_data).
-author("gextra").

%% API
-export([test/0]).

init_ets() ->
  ets:new(memdatabase, [bag, named_table]).

parse(File) ->
  {ok, F} = file:open(File, [read, raw]),
  parse(F, file:read_line(F), []).

parse(F, eof, Done) ->
  file:close(F),
  lists:reverse(Done);

parse(F, Line, Done) ->
  parse(F, file:read_line(F), [ parse_row_commodity_data(Line) | Done ]).

parse_row_commodity_data(Line) ->
  {ok, Data} = Line,
  %%io:fwrite(Data),
  LineList          = re:split(Data,"\,",[{return,list}]),
  ReportingCountry  = lists:nth(1, LineList),
  YearPeriod        = lists:nth(2, LineList),
  Year              = lists:nth(3, LineList),
  Period            = lists:nth(4, LineList),
  TradeFlow         = lists:nth(5, LineList), 
  Commodity         = lists:nth(6, LineList),
  PartnerCountry    = lists:nth(7, LineList),
  NetWeight         = lists:nth(8, LineList),
  Value             = lists:nth(9, LineList),
  IsReported        = lists:nth(10, LineList),
  ets:insert(memdatabase, {YearPeriod ++ ReportingCountry ++ Commodity , { ReportingCountry, Year, Period, TradeFlow, Commodity, PartnerCountry, NetWeight, Value, IsReported } }).


test() ->
  init_ets(),
  parse("/data/000-2010-1.csv").
```

Comment: An example of the tuples you store in the ETS table would help. It very much depends on what type of data and you represent and store it. Also how you read in the data would help.

Comment: added test code above. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It strongly depend what you mean by *splices it into a list, then create a tuple*. Especially splice into list can take a lot of memory. One byte can occupy 16B if split into list. It is 5.6GB with easy.

**EDIT**:

Try this:

```
parse(File) ->
  {ok, F} = file:open(File, [read, raw, binary]),
  ok = parse(F, binary:compile_pattern([<<$,>>, <<$\n>>])),
  ok = file:close(F).

parse(F, CP) ->
  case file:read_line(F) of
    {ok, Line} ->
      parse_row_commodity_data(Line, CP),
      parse(F, CP);
    eof -> ok
  end.

parse_row_commodity_data(Line, CP) ->
  [ ReportingCountry, YearPeriod, Year, Period, TradeFlow, Commodity,
    PartnerCountry, NetWeight, Value, IsReported]
      = binary:split(Line, CP, [global, trim]),
  true = ets:insert(memdatabase, {
         {YearPeriod, ReportingCountry, Commodity},
         { ReportingCountry, Year, Period, TradeFlow, Commodity,
           PartnerCountry, NetWeight, Value, IsReported}
       }).
```

Comment: added test code above. I am using regex split. thanks.

Comment: @gextra: So that is it. When you read data into lists it multiply occupied memory by factor of 16 in 64-bit VM. It is one word for each list value and one word for pointer to next cell. The word size is 8 so 16B for every character from input data. Keep your data in binary.

Comment: interesting solutions and thanks for pointing out to use binary. makes a lot of sense...

Comment: The `re` module works on both lists and binaries, but you should be specific and use `{return,binary}` for `re:split`.